# rust compiler error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\TestApp.exe` (exit code: 101)

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, egui, eframe

I'm creating a EGUI app with eframe and i've been testing it and compiling it to both WASM and windows. Recently it stopped compiling to windows(exe) due to this error.

```
error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\TestApp.exe` (exit code: 101)
```

the backtrace:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'assertion failed: min <= max', /rustc/90743e7298aca107ddaa0c202a4d3604e29bfeb6\library\core\src\num\f32.rs:1394:9
stack backtrace:
   0: std::panicking::begin_panic_handler
             at /rustc/90743e7298aca107ddaa0c202a4d3604e29bfeb6/library\std\src\panicking.rs:575
   1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at /rustc/90743e7298aca107ddaa0c202a4d3604e29bfeb6/library\core\src\panicking.rs:65
   2: core::panicking::panic
             at /rustc/90743e7298aca107ddaa0c202a4d3604e29bfeb6/library\core\src\panicking.rs:115
   3: core::f32::impl$0::clamp
             at /rustc/90743e7298aca107ddaa0c202a4d3604e29bfeb6\library\core\src\num\f32.rs:1394
   4: emath::pos2::Pos2::clamp
             at C:\Users\adavi\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\emath-0.21.0\src\pos2.rs:187
   5: egui_winit::window_settings::WindowSettings::clamp_window_to_sane_position<enum2$<eframe::native::run::UserEvent> >
             at C:\Users\adavi\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\egui-winit-0.21.0\src\window_settings.rs:132
   6: eframe::native::epi_integration::window_builder<enum2$<eframe::native::run::UserEvent> >
             at C:\Users\adavi\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\eframe-0.21.0\src\native\epi_integration.rs:127
   7: eframe::native::run::glow_integration::impl$2::on_event
             at C:\Users\adavi\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\eframe-0.21.0\src\native\run.rs:874
   8: winit::platform_impl::platform::event_loop::impl$3::run_return::closure$0<enum2$<eframe::native::run::UserEvent>,eframe::native::run::run_and_return::closure_env$0<eframe::native::run::glow_integration::GlowWinitApp> >
             at C:\Users\adavi\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\winit-0.28.1\src\platform_impl\windows\event_loop.rs:256
   9: alloc::boxed::impl$46::call_mut
             at /rustc/90743e7298aca107ddaa0c202a4d3604e29bfeb6\library\alloc\src\boxed.rs:1994
  10: winit::platform_impl::platform::event_loop::runner::impl$3::call_event_handler::closure$0
             at C:\Users\adavi\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\winit-0.28.1\src\platform_impl\windows\event_loop\runner.rs:250
  11: core::panic::unwind_safe::impl$23::call_once<tuple$<>,winit::platform_impl::platform::event_loop::runner::impl$3::call_event_handler::closure_env$0<enum2$<eframe::native::run::UserEvent> > >
             at /rustc/90743e7298aca107ddaa0c202a4d3604e29bfeb6\library\core\src\panic\unwind_safe.rs:271
  12: std::panicking::try::do_call
             at /rustc/90743e7298aca107ddaa0c202a4d3604e29bfeb6\library\std\src\panicking.rs:483
  13: std::panicking::try
             at /rustc/90743e7298aca107ddaa0c202a4d3604e29bfeb6\library\std\src\panicking.rs:447
  14: std::panic::catch_unwind
             at /rustc/90743e7298aca107ddaa0c202a4d3604e29bfeb6\library\std\src\panic.rs:137
  15: winit::platform_impl::platform::event_loop::runner::EventLoopRunner<enum2$<eframe::native::run::UserEvent> >::catch_unwind
             at C:\Users\adavi\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\winit-0.28.1\src\platform_impl\windows\event_loop\runner.rs:157
  16: winit::platform_impl::platform::event_loop::runner::EventLoopRunner<enum2$<eframe::native::run::UserEvent> >::call_event_handler<enum2$<eframe::native::run::UserEvent> >
             at C:\Users\adavi\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\winit-0.28.1\src\platform_impl\windows\event_loop\runner.rs:242
  17: winit::platform_impl::platform::event_loop::runner::EventLoopRunner<enum2$<eframe::native::run::UserEvent> >::call_new_events
             at C:\Users\adavi\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\winit-0.28.1\src\platform_impl\windows\event_loop\runner.rs:402
  18: winit::platform_impl::platform::event_loop::runner::EventLoopRunner<enum2$<eframe::native::run::UserEvent> >::move_state_to<enum2$<eframe::native::run::UserEvent> >
             at C:\Users\adavi\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\winit-0.28.1\src\platform_impl\windows\event_loop\runner.rs:312
  19: winit::platform_impl::platform::event_loop::runner::EventLoopRunner<enum2$<eframe::native::run::UserEvent> >::poll
             at C:\Users\adavi\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\winit-0.28.1\src\platform_impl\windows\event_loop\runner.rs:206
  20: winit::platform_impl::platform::event_loop::EventLoop<enum2$<eframe::native::run::UserEvent> >::run_return<enum2$<eframe::native::run::UserEvent>,eframe::native::run::run_and_return::closure_env$0<eframe::native::run::
glow_integration::GlowWinitApp> >
             at C:\Users\adavi\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\winit-0.28.1\src\platform_impl\windows\event_loop.rs:265
  21: eframe::native::run::run_and_return<eframe::native::run::glow_integration::GlowWinitApp>
             at C:\Users\adavi\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\eframe-0.21.0\src\native\run.rs:115
  22: eframe::native::run::glow_integration::run_glow::closure$0
             at C:\Users\adavi\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\eframe-0.21.0\src\native\run.rs:985
  23: eframe::native::run::with_event_loop::closure$0
             at C:\Users\adavi\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\eframe-0.21.0\src\native\run.rs:99
  24: std::thread::local::LocalKey<core::cell::RefCell<enum2$<core::option::Option<winit::event_loop::EventLoop<enum2$<eframe::native::run::UserEvent> > > > > >::try_with
             at /rustc/90743e7298aca107ddaa0c202a4d3604e29bfeb6\library\std\src\thread\local.rs:446
  25: std::thread::local::LocalKey<core::cell::RefCell<enum2$<core::option::Option<winit::event_loop::EventLoop<enum2$<eframe::native::run::UserEvent> > > > > >::with<core::cell::RefCell<enum2$<core::option::Option<winit::ev
ent_loop::EventLoop<enum2$<eframe::na
  26: eframe::native::run::with_event_loop
             at C:\Users\adavi\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\eframe-0.21.0\src\native\run.rs:92
  27: eframe::native::run::glow_integration::run_glow
             at C:\Users\adavi\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\eframe-0.21.0\src\native\run.rs:982
  28: eframe::run_native
             at C:\Users\adavi\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\eframe-0.21.0\src\lib.rs:199
  29: TestApp::main
             at .\src\main.rs:16
  30: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once<enum2$<core::result::Result<tuple$<>,enum2$<eframe::Error> > > (*)(),tuple$<> >
             at /rustc/90743e7298aca107ddaa0c202a4d3604e29bfeb6\library\core\src\ops\function.rs:251
note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.
error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\TestApp.exe` (exit code: 101)
```

This is my `main` function:

```
#[cfg(not(target_arch = "wasm32"))]
fn main() -> eframe::Result<()> {
    // Log to stdout (if you run with `RUST_LOG=debug`).
    tracing_subscriber::fmt::init();
    let native_options = eframe::NativeOptions::default();
    eframe::run_native(
        "Visualisation",
        native_options,
        Box::new(|cc| Box::new(TestApp::Visualisation::new(cc))),
    )
}
```

Comment: We cannot debug code you don't show, please include a [mre]. All we can tell with the info provided is that the error originated in line 16 of your `src/main.rs`.

Comment: main.rs just consists of creating a EGUI window
```#[cfg(not(target_arch = "wasm32"))]
fn main() -> eframe::Result<()> {

    // Log to stdout (if you run with `RUST_LOG=debug`).
    tracing_subscriber::fmt::init();

    let native_options = eframe::NativeOptions::default();

    eframe::run_native(
        "Visualisation",
        native_options,
        Box::new(|cc| Box::new(TestApp::Visualisation::new(cc))),
    )

}```

Comment: Don't post code in comments, as you've just experienced, that doesn't work well, [edit] your post and put it in between [code fences (```)](/help/formatting) each on their own line instead.

Comment: Nitpick: "it stopped compiling" is wrong here - in particular, `cargo build` should work just fine, it's the resulting executable that fails.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be the bug in `egui_winit 0.21.0`, [fixed](https://docs.rs/egui-winit/latest/src/egui_winit/window_settings.rs.html#136-141) in the next released version. Just update your `egui` dependencies, and all should be fine.